# Simplify triple integral over time differences

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I know that if I have the following integral
\begin{equation}
    \int_{-\infty}^t dt_1 e^{-|t-t_1|} f(t-t_1)
\end{equation}
by defining a new variable $\tau=t-t_1$, it can be transformed into
\begin{equation}
    \int_0^\infty d\tau e^{-\tau} f(\tau)
\end{equation}
which makes the integration much easier by removing the absolute value. I am now trying the same trick with a much-involved triple integral
\begin{equation}
    \int_{-\infty}^t dt_1 \int_{-\infty}^{t_1} dt_2 \int_{-\infty}^{t_2} dt_3 (e^{-|t-t_1|}e^{-|t_2-t_3|}+e^{-|t-t_3|}e^{-|t_2-t_1|}) f(t-t_1)g(t_1-t_2)h(t_2-t_3)l(t_3-t)
\end{equation}
The problem is that now if I define $\tau=t-t_1$, it will appear in the upper integration of the second integral. Is there any way to circumvent this?

Comment: In the first integral, note that $t_1 \in (-\infty,t]$, so you already know $t_1 \leq t$ (i.e., $t - t_1 \geq 0$) and therefore that $|t-t_1| = t-t_1$. In other words, you can already just drop the absolute value bars in the original expression.

Comment: I see, perfect, that will help! Still, I assume it is still not possible to find a change of variable to express the differences, right? At the first expression it's easy because it is just a two-time correlation function, but now I have a 4-times correlation function

Comment: Well, note that always $t_1\leq t$, and $t_2\leq t_1$, and $t_3\leq t_2$ by the same reasoning, so you also have that each of the quantities $t-t_1$, $t_1-t_2$, and $t_2-t_3$ are never negative. Also, $t_3\leq t_2 \leq t_1 \leq t$, so also $t-t_3$ is never negative. So, yes, you can do something similar with all of these.